# MongoDB Driver c# DateTime AddHours Query InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a collection of planning with a startDate and a duration in hours (totalDuration)

```
public class PlanningDTO
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
 
    [BsonElement("startDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("totalDuration")]
    public int TotalDuration { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the planning that are included in a date range.

I am using an API in .Net 3.1 with MongoDriver 2.12.3

I have tried things like:

```
GetPlanningsInDateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate){ 
var filter = Builders<PlanningDTO>
            .Filter
            .Where(pp => pp.StartDate.AddHours(pp.TotalDuration) >= startDate && pp.StartDate <= endDate);

var planningsInRange = await Db.GetCollection<PlanningDTO>("Plannings").Find(filter).ToListAsync();
return planningsInRange;
            }
```

or using Mongo.Driver.LINQ

```
var planningsInRange = await Db.GetCollection<PlanningDTO>("Plannings").AsQueryablew<PlanningDTO>()
.Where(pp => pp.StartDate.AddHours(pp.TotalDuration) >= startDate && pp.StartDate <= endDate).ToListAsync();
```

but what i get is en error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: {document}{startDate}.AddHours(Convert({document}{totalDuration}, Double)) is not supported.

If i do this kind of query without *AddHours()*, it works fine (no error) but then it is not what i want.

Any idea?

Comment: My guess would be that it's a limitation of the MongoDB query engine that turns LINQ into the underlying queries - it doesn't understand how to turn `AddHours()` into something it can transform into the query because it's a .NET method.

Comment: I think it must be something like this, some limitation of the mongo driver. But I cannot find any workaround

Comment: Is your DTO allowed to change? If so, to what extent?

Comment: Maybe it's beneficial to have an additional Property "EndDate" ?

Comment: Change in the DTO is a last resort option. It will not be allowed easily

Answer (score 1):

i believe you'd be able to do it with a projection like the following but it would be way inefficient than storing the `EndDate` in the database from the get go.

```cs
ProjectionDefinition<Plan, object> projection = @"
{
    _id: 1,
    startDate: 1,
    totalDuration: 1,
    ENDDATE: { $add: ['$startDate', { $multiply: ['$totalDuration', 3600000] }] }
}";

var filter = Builders<Plan>.Filter.Gte(p => p.StartDate, startDate);
    filter &= Builders<Plan>.Filter.Lte("ENDDATE", endDate);

var result = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Project(projection)
    .As<Plan>()
    .Match(filter)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I use this, I have an error " Element 'ENDDATE' does not match any field or property of class planningDTO. Does it means that I have to make a new classe with EndDate property   and then  map it to my DTO?

Comment: @frdrc sorry didn't test it properly. i've updated my answer with a working version.